# How matched tags percentage can be calculated in mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have 3 tables,
First one is playlists the other two are keywords and keywordmap.

I use to use the sql below to find playlists that sharing common tags.
I need to get common tag percent and order by it in mysql+php
Even If I can get matched tag count, I can calculate percentage in php later.

Tables are; in order playlists, keywords, keywordmap

```
|pid  |authorid |totaltrack|

|kid  |keyword  |used       |createdate|

|kmid |kwid     |plid       |
```

previous code;

```
SELECT p1.pid FROM keywordmap km
LEFT JOIN playlists p1 ON km.plid = p1.pid
WHERE kwid 
IN (
    SELECT kwid FROM playlists p2 LEFT JOIN keywordmap km2 
    ON p2.pid = km2.plid LEFT JOIN keywords kws
    ON km2.kwid = kws.kid WHERE p2.pid = 10
)
GROUP BY plid
```

Desired results are;

```
|plid |matchedtag|percentage
|234  |23        | 65 
|363  |21        | 55
|19   |18        | 34
|91   |1         | 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the answer. Rest of it percentage calculation based on user's total tag count.

```
SELECT p1.pid, COUNT(plid) as matched, p1.authorid FROM keywordmap km
LEFT JOIN playlists p1 ON km.plid = p1.pid
WHERE kwid 
IN (
    SELECT kwid FROM playlists p2 LEFT JOIN keywordmap km2 
    ON p2.pid = km2.plid LEFT JOIN keywords kws
    ON km2.kwid = kws.kid WHERE p2.pid = $pid
)
GROUP BY plid ORDER BY matched DESC
```